# How can I print data to a ready excel file with C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I had a question about a windows forms application.
I imported my data saved in the database into a datagridwieve, then pulled them into text boxes with cellsclick and from there
I want to print the data in the text box to the excel cell I want. For example I have date value
This is datetimepicer1. I want to print to (2.5) cell in Excel. or I want to print the data in the txtName field to Excel[5,6] cell in excel. While doing this, instead of opening a new excel sheet, I want to do this in an excel file I have.
Is something like this possible? If possible how can I do it?

Comment: Sure it's possible. You'll either have to write a library that understands how to interact with Excel or Excel files, find a ready made library that does that for you. Since Excel can be complicated and it's not good to reinvent the wheel, you'll probably want to locate a library. That's up to you to research, Stack Overflow isn't here to recommend those for you. I'll point you in the right direction though: use your favorite search engine to search for "C# excel" and also look check out [Awesome Dot Net](https://github.com/quozd/awesome-dotnet).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.